# How can I read input as two different answers

Tags: c#

Say I get the following question

Console.WriteLine("Which teams have faced eachother? - use Red vs Blue format");

Then my answer to the question above will have two teams. But how can read them as two seperate?
So that i only read [Red] [Blue], but the "vs" part inbetween as to be there.

I hope my you understood what I am trying to say. My english is not great.

best regards,

ps, as you can tell I am pretty new in programming.

edit: oh and this is all in C#

Comment: Will you always need the value before 'vs' and just after 'vs'?

Comment: Oh I need both. And then split into two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a regular expression:

```
Match m = Regex.Match("^(?<team1>\.+) vs (?<team2>\.+)$", userInput);
if (m.Success)
{
    string team1 = m.Groups["team1"].Value;
    string team2 = m.Groups["team2"].Value;
}
```

Please note that this may not be 100% syntactically correct - you have to refer to IntelliSense a bit - for example, I'm not sure whether the pattern is the first or the second parameter in `Match`, but I'm sure you get the picture.

Comment: A small question - That (?<team1>.+) is it something standard? With all the question mark and signs. And also if I capatilize the "T" does that mean that only Capatilized words are accepted. It's not something you have to find out if you don't know - it's just that I am not in a place where I can test it.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to read that you're new to C# :-) This `(?<team1>...)` thing forms a "named group" in a regular expression. The parenthesis makes a group which you can normally only access by index. The `?<xyz>` names the group, so you can use a name to access the value of the group, which is easier if you have nested groups. The `team1` and `team2` are totally arbitrary (but unique) names - they have no influence whatsoever on how the regular expression evaluates. The `\.+` is significant. It says: "at least one character".

Comment: What the regular expression means is: "Find everything before and after the text ' vs ' and name the first part 'team1' and the second part 'team2', so we can later get the matched values by name".

Comment: Oh thank you very much for that explanation. Thats really clear to me. I think I can use this code for my project. I hope I can proceed with my work when I get back home.  Actually I am going to try them all out for learning purposes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `String.Split()`:

```
var answers = userInput.Split(new String[] { "vs" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if (answers.Length == 2) {
    var red = answers[0];
    var blue = answers[1];
}
```

Comment: hope its always vs and not VS

Comment: With the code above, var red = "Which teams have faced eachother? - use, " and var blue = " Blue format"

Comment: I think you're interpreting the text "use Red vs Blue format" to be the format of the users' answer. To me this is instructional - i.e. Please use the format "RED vs BLUE" when providing your answer. To which a user might input: RedTeam1 vs BlueTeam5.

Comment: @V4Vendetta - Good catch, `String.Split()` is case-sensitive so any variant of "vs" would need special handling: Vs, VS, vS. They could just be included in the array initializer.

Comment: Oh thanks for that, will keep that in mind. I will put that in the question, so user don't do it wrong. And so that I don't have to put in more work.

Answer (score 2):

There are many option you can use Split function to make it array and remove "vs"
or simple use String.Replace("vs","") function to replace the "vs" string with blank value.

Answer (score 1):

U can read all as one string then split with "vs" seperator, then ull get table of 2 strings that u need

Answer (score 0):

Use the String.Split function, as others have suggested. This will split your string into an array of strings.  Then, identify which string in the array is the 'vs' string.  Take the value of the index prior to 'vs' and after 'vs'.  For example:

```
string input = "Which teams have faced eachother? - use Red vs Blue format";
string[] inputArray = input.Split( ' ' );

int vsLocation = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++ ) {
    if ( inputArray[i] == "vs" ) {
        vsLocation = i;
        break;
    }
}

if ( vsLocation > 0)  {
    string team1 = inputArray[vsLocation - 1];
    string team2 = inputArray[vsLocation + 1];
}
```

Comment: To clarify, when you use `String.Split()`, the separator item does not appear in the results as you've alluded to in your answer.

Comment: I just needed a minute to write the code myself.  Based on your answer above, you are correct.  However, I am using the space as a separator.

Comment: shouldn't           if ( inputArray[i] == "vs" ) {          be like " vs " so that spaces are gone aswell

Comment: No.  The string will be split based on the spaces, so the spaces themselves will not be included.

Comment: Noticed a couple of errors in my initial revision as well.  Here is a working sample.

Comment: When vsLocation = i; it's equal to 3 right ? Because "vs" is on the third array.  And because vsLocation is bigger than 0, it means that it will continue to do vslocation - 1 and vslocation + 1. Than you get array 2 and 4 which are Red and Blue.

Comment: For this particular example, vs ends up being 8 because it is the 9th element in the input string.  team1 gets set to the 7th element 'Red', and team2 gets set to the 9th element, 'Blue'.

Comment: Aah the input will only be "Red vs Blue" - But I am glad I saw this one, because now I know how to use If ( inputArray[i] == "vs" ) with of course the line above that one. It actually means, keep on going untill you find "vs" then -1 and +1 to find the last two words we are looking for